# Nome dos campos de um objeto genérico - reflection

Tags: c#, reflexão

Bom dia pessoal. 
Tenho um problema que acredito que possa ser resolvido com Reflection, porém eu não sei usar e espero que possam me ajudar na minha dificuldade.

Tenho uma objeto que será passado como parâmetro para um método específico. Esse método deve conseguir ler esse objeto genérico e identificar o nome de todos os campos deste objeto. Abaixo o exemplo.

```
public class Aluno
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}
}
```

O método abaixo vai receber esse objeto e precisa percorrê-lo e identificar o nome dos campos, ou seja, ele precisa descobrir que um campo se chama *Id* e o outro se chama *Nome*. Exemplo abaixo:

```
public void DescobridorDeNome(T Objeto)
{
    //Aqui ele vai descobrir o nome dos campos do objeto.
}
```

Então, neste método que acredito que usando o Reflection vai resolver. 
Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Valeu.

Comment: Quanto a duplicação da pergunta, me desculpem, mas eu não soube como procurar a pergunta, por isso postei explicando exatamente como eu precisaria. Foi mal mesmo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe um método da classe `Type` chamado `GetProperties`

```
public static void DescobridorDeNome<T>(T objeto)
{
    var props = objeto.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach(var prop in props)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name} = {prop.GetValue(objeto, null)}");
    }
}
```

Código completo pra teste:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    { 
        var aluno = new Aluno{ Id = 1, Nome = "LINQ" };
        DescobridorDeNome(aluno);
    }

    public static void DescobridorDeNome<T>(T objeto)
    {
        var props = objeto.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach(var prop in props)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name} = {prop.GetValue(objeto, null)}");
        }
    }
}

public class Aluno
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PEcUuG)</sup>

Comment: Resolveu meu problema. Muito, mas muito obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Basicamente, seria assim o método para descobrir os nomes dos campos de qualquer tipo, exemplo:

```
void DescobridorDeNome<T>(T objeto)
{
    var items = objeto.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Select(x => x.Name)
            .ToList();
}
```

onde `items` seria uma lista do tipo `string` (`List<string>`) com todos os nomes, além disso você consegue pegar valores, tipos de cada propriedade, e a reflexão deve ser utilizado quando realmente for necessário, faltou dizer o foco para utilizar isso, mas, muitas vezes é assim mesmo que resolve.

Um lembrete que passar um objeto o método `DescobridorDeNome` foi alterado para tal, sendo então um método genérico a partir disso.

Também pode ser feito um código que para um determinado tipo eu conheça suas propriedades, ou seja, não precisando da instância de um objeto, só passar o tipo, ***exemplo***:

```
static void DescobridorDeNomeGetType(Type t)
{
    var items = t.GetProperties()
            .Select(x => x.Name)
            .ToList();
}
```

[Um exemplo com instância e somente o tipo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ATci5x).

<sub>***Exemplo completo:***</sub>

```
class Program
{
    static void DescobridorDeNome<T>(T objeto)
    {
        var items = objeto.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Select(x => x.Name)
            .ToList();


        foreach (string name in items)
            Console.WriteLine(name);
    }

    static void DescobridorDeNomeGetType(Type t)
    {
        var items = t.GetProperties()
            .Select(x => x.Name)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var name in items)
            Console.WriteLine(name);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // com instância
        DescobridorDeNome(new Aluno());

        // só o tipo
        DescobridorDeNomeGetType(typeof(Aluno));
    }
}
```

Então tudo vai depender e qual momento utilizar, se precisar dos valores dos campos (*por exemplo*), vai precisar utilizar o que tem a instância da classe, agora se precisar descobrir o que tem nesse tipo utiliza a segunda opção.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Reflexão no .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Reflexão (C# e Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173183(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [PropertyInfo.PropertyType Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype(v=vs.100).aspx)